# Booting kernel failed : Invalid argument ( Ubuntu installing)

Tags: linux, installation, windows-10, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04

So I tried installing **"ubuntu-18.04.4"** which is located in Desktop, with **VirtualBox 16.1**. When I hit the start button it loads a bit that purple page then shows this error (couldn't take a screenshot) :

EDD: Error 0c00 reading sector 995464.
EDD: Error 0c00 reading sector 999930.
EDD: Error 0c00 reading sector 999931.
EDD: Error 0c00 reading sector 1021411.
**Booting kernel failed: Invalid argument**

I tried disabling windows Secure Boot but the problem remains.
I have **Windows10 64bits** and reserved 10GB for Ubuntu.Here's a screenshot of other configurations :
[image]

Thanks a lot!